# zsh: permission denied: ~/.bash_profile

Tags: bash, terminal, zsh

I am trying to run the following to set `env`, but I can not:

```
echo 'export ethereum_home=/Users/mattthomas/ethereum' >>~/.bash_profile
```

- Permissions for `.bash_profile`:

  ```
  -rw-r--r--    1 root    staff    447 Jun 17 21:50 .bash_profile
  ```

How can I write to `.bash_profile`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you executing the command as `root`, as your file has the following permissions:

```
-rw-r--r--    1 root    staff    447 Jun 17 21:50 .bash_profile
```

- You can write only with user `root` or you can use `sudo` with the command, e.g:

  ```
  sudo echo 'export ethereum_home=/Users/mattthomas/ethereum' >> ~/.bash_profile
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have root privileges, you can not write to .bash_profile. check to see if your .bash_profile has another profile that it sources from. Run

```
cat ~/.bash_profile
```

and look for something like

```
. ./blah-blah_profile
```

or something like that. Usually sysadmins do not let the users mess with the main bash_profile but give them a user defined profile to play with.

It is not uncommon to see something like:

```
. ~/${USER}_profile
```

or

```
. ~/${USER}.rc
```

etc. pay attention to the space right after the . (dot) character at the beginning of line. That is what "source"s your profile instead of executing it as a script.

If you need further help update your question with the contents of your .bash_profile